# Resize 3D stack of images in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array, which is a stack of 100 300x300 images. I want to resize all the images in the stack to be 200x200. I tried to use the numpy resize function:

```
import numpy as np

img_stack_sm = np.resize(img_stack, (100, 200, 200))
```

...but doing so scrambles the images (as shown by plotting). How can this be done in one pass? Thank you.

Comment: numpy resize just chops off values. Read its docs.  You want an image resizing that interpolates new values or resamples.

Comment: How would you resize one image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just used a for loop in the end and cv2:

```
import cv2

width = 200
height = 200
img_stack_sm = np.zeros((len(img_stack), width, height))

for idx in range(len(img_stack)):
    img = img_stack[idx, :, :]
    img_sm = cv2.resize(img, (width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img_stack_sm[idx, :, :] = img_sm
```

Comment: You should use `np.zeros((len(img_stack), height, width))` as Numpy works per rows, while OpenCV wants classic width x height.